# Basic Swift Package Dependency understanding

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a workspace with two projects that both use a swift package.

1. MyApp

   - PackageA@latest
2. MyFramework

   - PackageA@latest

Even when just using the latest version of the package in each project, I can't link `MyApp`. I get the following error:

```
Swift package product 'PackageA' is linked as a static library by 'MyApp' and 'MyFramework'. This will result in duplication of library code.
```

This seems like a very basic thing to support so I assume I'm just not setting it up properly. Any help would be appreciated.